# javascript modules : "export * as" in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, export, es6-modules

I just joined a new project and stumbled upon the following JavaScript export syntax (global export with alias):

```
export * as actions from './Something.actions.js';
```

The syntax seems to be working, but I've never seen it before and it is marked as an error in visual studio code. Is it a valid syntax ? Can someone explain why vscode thinks this syntax is incorrect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you try changing `actions` to something else and see what you get? Also try restarting the Code once..

Comment: The syntax seems correct. `*` actually means `all`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently an experimental syntax (stage 1), supported via Babel but not supported natively in visual studio code at the moment.

For more information:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45139

Answer (score 1):

For people like me that wondered how to achieve the export...

From the excellent links provided by [Fab313's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132002/1030527):

> #### Proposed addition:
>
> The proposed addition follows this same symmetric pattern:
>
> Importing a namespace exotic object (existing):
>
> ```
> import * as ns from "mod";
> ```
>
> Exporting that name (existing):
>
> ```
> import * as ns from "mod";
> export {ns};
> ```
>
> Symmetric "export from" (proposed):
>
> ```
> export * as ns from "mod";
> ```

So to fix the error, change your code to:

```
import * as actions from './Something.actions.js';
export { actions };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a syntax error in your code, try fixing the problem by putting some brackets around it, like this:

```
export  { * as actions } from './Something.actions.js';
```

If should you have any further questions, you could check this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

```
export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };
```

Comment: Brackets are for named exports, this is a global export with an alias, so it's not solving the problem.